# Have I rephrased this sentence correctly?

Tags: phrase-usage

The original:

> When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly
>   published the article **as it had originally been written**.

My version:

> When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly
>   published the article **in its original form**.

Does these 2 sentences mean the same thing?

Feel free to provide other paraphrases.

Comment: What is your specific concern about your rephrasing? Why do you think it might not mean the same thing? If you [edit] your question to explain a little bit more we should be able to take it off hold (and it will be more relevant to other learners!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts are that both these sentences mean the same thing.  If you're looking for other versions:

> When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly
>   published the unedited article.
>
> When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly
>   published the originally submitted copy of the article.